# Merge with regex in pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, merge

I have two tables A and B which I need to join via regular expresion:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a_df = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['A','B','C','D','E','F'],
                    'cola1': ['c1A','c1B', 'c1C', 'c1D', 'c1E', 'c1F'],
                    'cola2': ['c2A','c2B', 'c2C', 'c2D', 'c2E', 'c2F']})
b_df = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['A|B|C','E|F'],
                    'colb1': ['cb1ABC','cb1EF'],
                    'colb2': ['cb2ABC','c2EF']})
```

The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
a_b_merge = pd.DataFrame({'key_a': ['A','B','C','D','E','F'],
                          'cola1': ['c1A','c1B', 'c1C', 'c1D', 'c1E', 'c1F'],
                          'cola2': ['c2A','c2B', 'c2C', 'c2D', 'c2E', 'c2F'],
                          'key_b': ['A|B|C', 'A|B|C', 'A|B|C', np.nan, 'E|F', 'E|F'],
                          'colb1': ['cb1ABC','cb1ABC', 'cb1ABC', np.nan, 'c1E', 'c1F'],
                          'colb2': ['cb2ABC','cb2ABC', 'cb2ABC', np.nan, 'c2EF', 'c2EF']})
```

My solution in SQL would be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN table_b b
    ON b.key LIKE CONCAT('%', a.key, '%')
```

Is there any way to achieve this using pandas `merge()`? If not, which would be the most elegant solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a temporary column that contains the extract of b_df.key, merge the two dataframes, and drop the temporary column:

```
a_df.merge(
    b_df.assign(temporary=lambda x: x.key.str.split("|")).explode("temporary"),
    left_on="key",
    right_on="temporary",
    how="outer",
    suffixes=("_a", "_b"),
).iloc[:, :-1]



key_a   cola1   cola2   key_b   colb1   colb2
0   A   c1A      c2A    A|B|C   cb1ABC  cb2ABC
1   B   c1B      c2B    A|B|C   cb1ABC  cb2ABC
2   C   c1C      c2C    A|B|C   cb1ABC  cb2ABC
3   D   c1D      c2D    NaN      NaN    NaN
4   E   c1E      c2E    E|F    cb1EF    c2EF
5   F   c1F      c2F    E|F    cb1EF    c2EF
```